# Issues with Python json decoding

Tags: python, json

I'm new to python and picked up this book  "Python for Data Analysis"
pydata-book

Anyway I tried the very first code in the book on page 18 and I keep getting error. Tried to download the entire file again but still have the same error.

This is the error message

```
UnicodeDecodeError Traceback (most recent call last)
in ()
----> 1 records=[json.loads(line) for line in open(path)]

in (.0)
----> 1 records=[json.loads(line) for line in open(path)]

/Users/gambit_remy08/anaconda/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py in decode(self, input, final)
24 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
25 def decode(self, input, final=False):
---> 26 return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
27
28 class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 6987: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here is the link to Github on the above thread
https://github.com/wesm/pydata-book/issues/48#issuecomment-266333303

Comment: What Python version do you use? Looks like Unicode issue. Also, please, post your json data.

Comment: The last line in that file is an empty line. Delete that last line and your code will work perfect.

Comment: `records = [json.loads(line) for line in open(path, encoding='utf8')]`

Answer (score 0):

The UnicodeDecodeError normally happens when decoding an str string from a certain coding. Since codings map only a limited number of str strings to unicode characters, an illegal sequence of str characters will cause the coding-specific decode() to fail.

Refer [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UnicodeDecodeError)

To solve this you can use `your_string.decode('utf8', 'ignore')`

```
records=[json.loads(line.decode('utf8', 'ignore')) for line in open(path)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've find a solution for it. Basically just need to used this and is working fine so far

```
records = [json.loads(line) for line in open(path, encoding='utf8')]
```